# Why webView.loading not giving me false when the page is loaded - Swift

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift

So i have a webview and i want to trigger something when the webview is loaded. So i have a timer which i have written to check every .5 sec if the webview is loaded or not. Some how my Webview.loading always returns true even when the site has loaded.

Sample Code:
On ViewDidLoad:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("runSomethingCool"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

var url = NSURL(string:"http://mycoolURL/")
var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
webView.loadRequest(req)
```

And outside in my runSomethingCool function i have this.

```
println(webView.loading);
```

Looks like its printing `TRUE` always!

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What does `println(webView.loading)` print out before you call loadRequest?

Comment: You should just use the web view's delegate methods that tell you when it starts and stops loading frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use UIWebViewDelegate and webViewDidFinishLoad:

No need to continuously check...